# float multiple elements right and bottom

Tags: html, css, position

once it's multiple elements a simple

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```

won't help since it will overlay the multiple elements

Here is a fiddle of my atempt : http://jsfiddle.net/7uYUP/
(it's the .interaction elements that I want to float right and bottom, right now they only float right)

I was hoping not having to resort to JS..

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve and how that's different from the fiddle result...

Comment: to float right and bottom.. right now it only floats right

Comment: What div is "it"? Where should the green div be in relation to the yellow ones?

Comment: it's the .interaction (yellow) that i want, sorry about that, if you notice they are bigger than the green, so it creates a scroll instead of floating them to the bottom of the green div

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the height different between your green and yellow boxes (10pt vs 40pt). You can adjust for that with `margin-top`:

```
.interaction{
   height:40pt;
   width:100pt;
   background-color:yellow;
   float:right;
   border: 1pt solid blue;
   margin-top:-32pt;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7uYUP/2/

Comment: no, the .interaction should float to the bottom of the .wrapme

Comment: there are two `div.interaction`: are they side by side? on one on top of the other?

Comment: yes but this way the .interaction can never change height. just found a solution : .container{height:auto}

Comment: ah well, if `.interaction` can change its height, that changes everything! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>

<div id="container"><div>

    <div class="interaction leftalign">
    </div>

    <div class="interaction">
    </div>  

</div></div>  

</body>  



 body{
      background-color:red;
    }

    #container{
     position:absolute;
      height:10pt;
      width:100%;
      background-color:green;
     bottom:0;
    } 

    #container > div {
      position:relative;
      height:100%;
    }  

    .interaction{
    height:40pt;
    width:100pt;
    background-color:yellow;
    float:right;
    border: 1pt solid blue;
    }  

    .interaction.leftalign {
      float:left;
    }
```